# JavaMail Exception in MyEclipse:javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed; nested exception is: javax.mail.MessagingException:

Tags: jakarta-mail

i am developing a simple web application using mail, with MyEclipse8.0.1 and Weblogic8.0 as server. Following is my code for sending email,it works well for console but when i m running it with myeclipse and Weblogic,it shows following error:

javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed; nested exception is: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465

Here is my Code in jsp:

```
<%
try {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
        p.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        p.put("mail.smtp.port","465");  
        p.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.debug","true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        p.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        Session s = Session.getInstance(p,new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("user","pass");}});
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(s);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("toaddr@gmail.com"));
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("toAddr@gmail.com"));
        msg.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
        msg.setSubject("MySub");
        msg.setText("Body");
        Transport.send(msg);
        out.println("Mail sent successfully");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  //e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
  out.println("Exception : " + e);
}


%>
```

One Interesting thing happened here is when i tried same code by starting MyEclipse Tomcat server and run the code, it send successfully to my gmail account as it was working from console program. but again when i tried above code with Weblogic 8.0, it showed me exception "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465 ".

I dont know what is going wrong, whether in the code or some special setting in server. So please please experts, guide me.
Thanks a ton, in advance.

Comment: I think some additional class methods or mail.smtp.xxxx setting may be missing by me, or, may be, there must be some setting for weblogic which can work for it, as it is going well with Tomcat integrated with MyEclipse.? Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Are Tomcat and WebLogic running on the same machine?  Possibly there's a firewall or anti-virus product preventing you from connecting.